# set url string in routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have in my component public variables url and title string like this:

```
const url: string = 'locator;name=Test';
const title: string = 'Test';
```

And I want to use it in my template for links like this:

```
<a mat-button [routerLink]="'/' + url">{{title}}</a>
```

The problem is that generated links are all wrong. I know routerLink can be used statically with string but then how to provide variable to the template because this way is not working:

```
<a mat-button routerLink="'/' + url">{{title}}</a>
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm receiving those links from service and I can not refactor it. For now I'm solving this like this but I have problem because webpage get reloaded each time I click those links:

```
<a mat-button [href]="'/' + url">{{title}}</a>
```

Comment: your url 'locator;name=Test' isn't dynamic, how do you get this from server?

Comment: We have features like favorite link in our app. We are sending to the webserver url as a string. When we getting this back I get url in the same form but I can not use it as I though initially.

Answer (score 5):

try below syntax make it url variable dyamic :

```
[routerLink]="['/', url]"
```

Comment: This also is not working. It changes characters in resulting url like all solutions below.

Comment: I think I will write my own directive based on routerLink src but inside I will need to invoke router.navigateByUrl().

Comment: ok than only pass url varible like [routerLink]="[url]" and make route in your app.routing.ts like
{ path: ":url",    component: IndexComponent} its woring for me

Comment: I found a solution and it woks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50469918/752775 Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

good:    `routerLink = "/{{url}}"`

or

best:    `[routerLink] = " '/' + url "`

**update:**

```
[routerLink]="[" '/' + getUrl(url) ", {queryParams: {name: title}}]
```

in component:

```
const url: string = 'locator;name=Test';
const title: string = 'Test';

getUrl(url:string):string {
    let res = url.split(";");
    return res[0];
}
```

Comment: This is not working because it change some characters in url. Given: `locator;name=mcdonalds` is changed to `locator;name%3Dmcdonalds`

Comment: @MarcinKapusta you should pass it by query param:```[routerLink]="[" '/' + url ", {queryParams: {name: 'mcdonalds'}}]```

Comment: I don't want to parse url from the server and change this url string to some parameters just to satisfy routerLink. Is there any easier way. I have valid url string already and I don't need to generate it one more time.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta '=' is a special character in angular router link and so you can't pass it as string in url but you can You can override Angular's [DefaultUrlSerializer](https://angular.io/api/router/DefaultUrlSerializer) to pass the '=', but in your case the good way is to change your recieved url.

Comment: I think the best solution is to write my own directive that will be calling under the hood `router.navigateByUrl('/' + myUrlString)` instead of using routerLink which is limited and is expecting array of parameters.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta i updated the answer, you can use it if you want.

Comment: Thanks everybody for help. I choose to design directive. It is in one of the answers if somebody is interested.

Comment: @MarcinKapusta, did you attempt my answer below. Shouldn't need to add weight with a Directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution that is working for me. All of the above solution was based on processing my valid input url. After processing some characters were missing, some were replaced, unescaped etc... This solution don't change url string at all and use it during navigations. It is based on routerLink source from angular github. I left only features that I need in my particular case.

```
import { Attribute, Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, Renderer2, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RouterEvent, NavigationEnd, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({ selector: 'a[routerUrlLink]' })
export class RouterUrlLinkWithHref implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

    @HostBinding('attr.target') @Input() target: string;
    @Input() skipLocationChange: boolean;
    @Input() replaceUrl: boolean;

    private url: string;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private preserve: boolean;

    // the url displayed on the anchor element.
    @HostBinding() href: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {
        this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((s: RouterEvent) => {
            if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.updateTargetUrlAndHref();
            }
        });
    }

    @Input()
    set routerUrlLink(url: string | UrlTree) {
        if (url instanceof UrlTree) {
            this.url = url.toString();
        } else {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }

    @Input()
    set preserveQueryParams(value: boolean) {
        if (isDevMode() && <any>console && <any>console.warn) {
            console.warn('preserveQueryParams is deprecated, use queryParamsHandling instead.');
        }
        this.preserve = value;
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {}): any { this.updateTargetUrlAndHref(); }
    ngOnDestroy(): any { this.subscription.unsubscribe(); }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event.button', '$event.ctrlKey', '$event.metaKey', '$event.shiftKey'])
    onClick(button: number, ctrlKey: boolean, metaKey: boolean, shiftKey: boolean): boolean {
        if (button !== 0 || ctrlKey || metaKey || shiftKey) {
            return true;
        }

        if (typeof this.target === 'string' && this.target != '_self') {
            return true;
        }

        const extras = {
            skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
            replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
        };
        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.url, extras);
        return false;
    }

    private updateTargetUrlAndHref(): void {
        this.href = this.locationStrategy.prepareExternalUrl(this.url);
    }

}

function attrBoolValue(s: any): boolean {
    return s === '' || !!s;
}
```

How to use it.
Import to your module, and in template use it like this:

```
<a mat-button [routerUrlLink]="'/' + urlStringOrUrlTree">Link Label</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try this syntax:

`<a routerLink="/{{url}}"></a>`

I have had success with this in the past.
Will work in `*ngFor` loops as well.

Comment: I tired this. It converts input url string and unescape some characters. Not work in my case.